Retrofit 2 PATCH call not working on physical device Android Studio
I am developing an app in android studio (java) and it runs fine when I use it on the emulator but when I use it on my physical device(OnePlus 8T) the PATCH call does not work, it's the only call that does not work, all my other calls work. It does not return any error, and when i use it with an api tester on the same device it works fine, I can't really wrap my head around this.
This is my gradle:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")



}


secrets {
    // Optionally specify a different file name containing your secrets.
    // The plugin defaults to "local.properties"
    propertiesFileName = "secrets.properties"

    // A properties file containing default secret values. This file can be
    // checked in version control.
    defaultPropertiesFileName = "local.defaults.properties"

    // Configure which keys should be ignored by the plugin by providing regular expressions.
    // "sdk.dir" is ignored by default.
    ignoreList.add("keyToIgnore") // Ignore the key "keyToIgnore"
    ignoreList.add("sdk.*")       // Ignore all keys matching the regexp "sdk.*"
}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.progetto_v1"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.progetto_v1"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments["room.schemaLocation"] =
                    "$projectDir/schemas"
            }
        }
    }





    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true


    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    val room_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")



    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")
    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9")

    val camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
}

These are the calls I implemented:
package com.example.progetto_v1;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.PATCH;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.http.Body;

public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("users/")
    Call<SignUpResponse> register();
    @GET("users/{id}")
    Call<User> getUser(@Path("id") int id, @Query("sid") String sid);

    @GET("users")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers(@Query("sid") String sid, @Query("lat") float lat, @Query("lon") float lon);

    @PATCH("users/{id}")
    Call<Void> updUser(@Path("id") int id, @Body UpdateRequestBody updateRequestBody);


    @GET("objects/{id}")
    Call<Item> getItem(@Path("id") int id, @Query("sid") String sid);

    @GET("ranking")
    Call<List<RankingUser>> getRanking(@Query("sid") String sid);

    @GET("objects")
    Call<List<Item>> getItems(@Query("sid") String sid, @Query("lat") float lat, @Query("lon") float lon);

    @POST("objects/{id}/activate")

    Call<ActivateResponse> activateItem(@Path("id") int id, @Body ActivateRequestBody activateRequestBody);

}


Have you checked you aren't trying to make a request to an HTTP endpoint instead of HTTPS? If so, for development purposes you can set usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the manifest but be sure to remove it before publishing!
